# Session Scoped Dependency Injection vs Caching in Data Access Layer

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

The issue at hand is that I don't want to repeatedly hit the DB to look up user information for the logged in user over the course of the many requests made within a single session.

My first inclination is to use Session Scoped Dependency Injection, however this isn't possible with out of the box DI features provided by Microsoft. I could install Autofac and that seems like a perfectly reasonable solution to me, however I seem to recall reading why Microsoft didn't include the ability to do this because they felt it was a bad practice... but I don't recall what their reasons were at the moment.

Then it occurred to me that the way people at Microsoft would probably handle this is through the fact that Entity Framework would just cache the results. However, I'm not using EF and the solution I'm using does not provide caching though I could easily add some caching to it.

So I'm wondering if I should 1) Install Autofac or 2) Add caching features to my data access layer.

Are there any serious reasons I should avoid 1) (i.e. not avoid installing Autofac generally, but doing it for the purpose of using Session Scoped DI, obviously)? Because I think that's what I will probably end up doing unless I can find a substantial reason not to.

Comment: Do you foresee the possibility of other features you may use from (1) Autofac (2) Caching features? Then pick the appropriate option. If not, pick the option which causes you less effort.

Comment: @Doc Brown that's the whole idea. But I don't know what I don't know, so just doing my due diligence to make sure I'm not missing any significantly important information before making a decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the main problem with session scope is, when does it end? Effectively you are making a cache and holding on to X sessions for Y long. Exceed those limit and you hit the database again.

Same problem with a cache, you're just being more upfront about it.

The problem with caches in general is that you normally load balance your servers, so a user doesn't hit the one with the cache each time.

First off, your database will implement its own cache on frequent queries. Trust it to be fast.

Secondly, you can get around looking up user information at all if you use a JWT, or just sign a cookie.

Comment: Jwt? What does that stand for?

Comment: json web token https://jwt.io/

Comment: Good points. I would say 30 minutes from last request is a good starting point for ending sessions. And you can configure load balancing to send users to the same server. I generally agree though and likely will use a cookie for basic user info. There are future cases I have in mind though involving more data than I'd want to put in a cookie

Comment: It's very strange someone downvoted your answer, and without commenting. Sometimes I wish they had a requirement that if you downvote, you must comment.